# Saving the FIRST value of a ajax requests in jQuery (post)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a "betting" script using jQuery/JS/PHP.

I'm developing an automated system with advanced parameters, such as the ability to increase the amount or decrease the amount on loss or win.

I also want to have the ability to "return to base bet" on loss or win, but how can I save the very first value entered that starts the process and have it return to that value if the boxes are checked?

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      function updateValuesAuto() {
        // Grab all the value just incase they're needed.
        var multiplier_auto = $('#multiplier_auto').val();
        var percentage_auto = $('#percentage_auto').val();
        var bet_amount_auto = $('#bet_amount_auto').val();
        var profit_amount_auto = $('#profit_amount_auto').val();

            multiplier_auto = (100-1)/percentage_auto;
            profit_amount_auto = (bet_amount_auto*multiplier_auto)-bet_amount_auto;

                $('#multiplier_auto').val(multiplier_auto);
                $('#percentage_auto').val(percentage_auto);
                $('#bet_amount_auto').val(bet_amount_auto);
                $('#profit_amount_auto').val(profit_amount_auto);
      }

      $('#multiplier_auto').keyup(updateValuesAuto);
      $('#percentage_auto').keyup(updateValuesAuto);
      $('#bet_amount_auto').keyup(updateValuesAuto);
      $('#profit_amount_auto').keyup(updateValuesAuto);



var runI   = null;
var $run   =  $('#start');
var $times =  $('#amount_bets');
var $stop =  $('#stop');

$run.on('click', function() {  
  event.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $stop.attr('disabled', false);
    var ran = 0;
    var val = parseInt($times.val(), 10);
    if(isNaN(val) || val === 0 ) return false;

     runI = setInterval(function() {
        if( ran < val ) {
          var base_bet = $('#bet_amount_auto').val();
          $.ajax({
            url: './requests/bet.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { amount: $('#bet_amount_auto').val(), chance: $('#percentage_auto').val(), multiplier: $('#multiplier_auto').val(), profit: $('#profit_amount_auto').val() },
          }).done(function(result) {
            var result = JSON.parse(result);

              if( result.result == 'win' ) {
                $('#bet_amount_auto').val($('#bet_amount_auto').val() * $('#wini').val());
                  updateValuesAuto();
                    if($('#wreturn').is(':checked') == true) {
                      $('#bet_amount_auto').val(base_bet);
                    }
              }
              else if( result.result == 'loss' ) {
                $('#bet_amount_auto').val($('#bet_amount_auto').val() * $('#lossi').val());
                  updateValuesAuto();
                    if($('#lreturn').is(':checked') == true) {
                      $('#bet_amount_auto').val(base_bet);
                    }
              }
              ran++;
          });
        }

        else {
           clearInterval(runI);
           $run.attr('disabled', false);
        }
    }, 500);
});

$stop.on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    clearInterval(runI);
    $run.attr('disabled', false);
});

});
```

Comment: you add a variable `firstbet` that you set on first bet change...

Comment: Can you give an example..?  I tried that with `var base_bet`

Comment: can't see what you tried

Comment: var base_bet = $('#bet_amount_auto');

Read the updateValuesAuto function too..

Comment: Nobody have an answer?

Comment: you sound like an editor, not like a developer

Comment: Editor?  Read the past questions I have... I wrote this could myself.  If you can't help don't speak.

Comment: you're asking people to think the solution for you while not showing any sign that you have even attempted to come up with a solution by yourself,  your problem is very basic if you're an analyst it should take less time to find one of the many possible solution than ask the question here

Comment: I showed a sign?  Did you not read my prior comment?  Please get off of my question now.